# Joining two Kafka KTable results in a Nullpointer in RocksDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to join two Kafka Stream DSL `KTable` using:

```java
KTable<String, String> source = builder.table("stream-source");
KTable<String, String> target = builder.table("stream-target");
source.join(target, new ValueJoiner<String, String, String>() {
    public String apply(String value1, String value2) {
        return value1 + ":" + value2;
    }
});
```

I have made sure that both the keys and the values are not `null`:

```java
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
for(int i = 0; i < PERSONS_SOURCE.length; i++) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("stream-source",     Long.toString(i + 1L), PERSONS_SOURCE[i]));
}
for(int i = 0; i < PERSONS_TARGET.length; i++) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("stream-target", Long.toString(i + 1L), PERSONS_TARGET[i]));
}
producer.close();
```

But the application reports that there is a null pointer in the RocksDB layer concerning the partition.

> [2016-07-17 21:58:04,682] ERROR User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1 for group streams-persons2 failed on partition assignment (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.put(RocksDB.java:432)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.putInternal(RocksDBStore.java:299)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.access$200(RocksDBStore.java:62)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore$3.restore(RocksDBStore.java:206)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.restoreActiveState(ProcessorStateManager.java:245)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.register(ProcessorStateManager.java:210)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.register(ProcessorContextImpl.java:116)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:202)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue was due to the streams being created in the application code instead of using the command:-

```
kafka-topics --create --topic stream-a --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

Seems that the join requires the partition information to work.